# How does SQL server handle connections that performs different tasks?

Tags: sql-server

I just want to know what happen if a table is being truncated by another connection and the other connection is retrieving the data out of it?

Let say, the first connection is retrieving thousands of rows, then after a few seconds another connection is truncating the said table. does the first connection `locks` the table and restrict the second connection from truncating until the first connection is done or otherwise?

I know the use of `#temptables` to avoid this complicated scenario but I want to know how SQL Server handle this kind of situation.

Thank you.

Comment: This will likely be better suited on [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com), however, it is unlikely that a `TRUNCATE` operation will succeed if the table is in use. Likely it'll have to wait for the (other) transaction to be completed or be chosen as the deadlock victim. But then, that does depend on the query hints, isolation settings,and dead lock options you have (if you're using those settings).

Comment: This is *thoroughly* described in the docs. The behavior is affected by the isolation level of each connection and whether snapshot isolation is used or not. TRUNCATE is essentially a DELETE and handled the same way as far as transaction isolation is concerned.

Comment: You need to think about what you really want to do. Why would one user read a table while another *deleted* everything in it, and what do *you* want to happen in that case? With snapshot isolation you can have the reader read a *snapshot* of the data while a writer deletes rows. With the `READ COMMITED` isolation level and up both `TRUNCATE TABLE x` and `DELETE FROM x` will wait because they are atomic.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is the `lock` mechanism that controls the different tasks:

Let's say, connection 1 reads tableX, and connection2 also reads tableX, then both connection hold the lock called `shared lock`, and they are compatible with each other, so no prob.

Another scenario, connection 1 reads the tableX, so it holds the `shared lock`; then connetion 2 tries to update or delete the rows, then what happens is that it waits for the first connection 1 to finish reading, then able to continue.

Answer (score 0):

> does the first connection locks the table and restrict the second
>   connection from truncating until the first connection is done or
>   otherwise?

Yes, exactly so.

It's impossible to `truncate` a table while some other session does a `select` from it.

It does not depend on `transaction isolation level` because table `truncation` needs `Sch-M` on a table and this lock is incompatible with all the other locks.

In case of `read committed` the first session already has `IS` on a table and this conflicts with `Sch-M`.

In case of `read uncommitted` the first session has `Sch-S` on a table that conflicts with `Sch-M`.

In case of `read committed snapshot`/`snapshot` the reading session also takes `Sch-S` lock that conflicts with `Sch-M` so in every case the `truncate` operation waits the select session to release its `lock` on a table level.